# Struggling with implementing Update, Delete, and View in LangChain API

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I have successfully implemented the "create" and "askquestion" LangChain API endpoints, which are working as expected. However, I am facing challenges with the "update," "delete," and "view" functionalities.

I am using LangChain in conjunction with Vector db, pinecone for local storage, Python Flask for API development, and OpenAI for chat completion and embeddings.

Specifically, I am encountering difficulties with the following functionalities:

- Update: I am unable to update a particular title or content based on the provided ID. The update should include modifying the content as well as updating the associated embeddings.
- Delete: I need assistance in implementing the deletion of a specific entry, including both the title and content, along with its corresponding embeddings.
- View: I am unable to retrieve and display the ID, title, and content in the response.

How could I implement the desired functionalities correctly?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import uuid
import os
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import openai
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import pinecone

pinecone.init(api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY, environment=PINECONE_API_ENV)
index_name = "knowledge-base"
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
print(index.describe_index_stats())
# pinecone.deinit()

app = Flask(__name__)

knowledge_base = []


@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def add_entry():
    data = request.get_json()
    title = data["title"]
    content = data["content"]

    entry_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        deployment="embedding-ada-002", model="text-embedding-ada-002")
    pinecone.init(api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY, environment=PINECONE_API_ENV)
    vectorstore = Pinecone.from_texts(
        [content], embeddings, index_name=index_name, namespace="knowledge")
    # pinecone.deinit()

    entry = {"id": entry_id, "title": title, "content": content}
    knowledge_base.append(entry)

    return jsonify(entry)
```